# fastcgi_cache_valid vs. fastcgi_cache_path "inactive" parameter?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php-fastcgi

If I've config

```
fastcgi_cache_path /opt/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=TEST:100m inactive=40m;
..
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_cache_valid 30m;
```

How long will my cache stored in the `path` above?

Answer (score 8):

`fastcgi_cache_valid` is used to define caching time for replies without "X-Accel-Expires", “Expires” or “Cache-Control” headers.
`fastcgi_cache_path ... inactive=` is used to define how long objects should be keeped in cache without accessing from browser.

So in your case with `fastcgi_cache_valid 30m` and `fastcgi_cache_path ... inactive=40m` all replies from original server without any Cache-control headers will be valid for 30 minutes (but could be used after 30 minutes in case of problems with original server if `fastcgi_cache_use_stale` is configured).
But cached object will be removed from cache if there will be no request for that object from users for 40 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question that actually I also added "fastcgi_ignore_headers..", so my understanding is, at 31 minute, even thought the object is still in the cache and is active, my origin server will be contacted again for the request since it is no longer valid, right? So `fastcgi_cache_valid` should be always greater than `inactive`, right?

Comment: You are right that origin server will be contacted at 31 minute.

Comment: As for `fastcgi_cache_valid` should be always greater than `inactive` -- they are totally independent values. `cache_valid` is used to determine how long this object is actual. While `inactive` is used to find non-popular objects and remove them from cache to reduce space usage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand they are independent but what I mean there is no point to set `inactive` greater than `fastcgi_cache_valid` since the cache is no longer valid, there is no need to store them in cache.

Comment: You are right and in your case you can use lower `inactive` value. But you should consider that if you ever plan to use `fastcgi_cache_use_stale` functionality.

Comment: See also this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/913135/144798